# How can I install Perl modules that are not on CPAN?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use the program O-Saft to verify my SSL certificates.  I'm using p5 on FreeBSD.  The git sources of O-Saft contain two modules called SSLhello.pm and SSLinfo.pm.  These modules are not found on CPAN.  Where do I install these modules so Perl can utilize them?

This is my env variable:

```bash
PERL5LIB="/home/kevdog/perl5/lib/perl5${PERL5LIB:+:${PERL5LIB}}"; export PERL5LIB;
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="/home/kevdog/perl5${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT:+:${PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT}}"; export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT;
```

Comment: O-Saft does not need to be installed. See the [README](https://github.com/OWASP/O-Saft/blob/master/README): "*O-Saft  can be executed from within the unpacked or cloned directory, installation is not necessary.*" But there's also an `INSTALL.sh` script if you want to install it anyway.

Comment: @melpomene, I believe that installs (copies?) the application rather than installing the Perl modules for external use.

Comment: @KevDog, I'm not convinced those are modules are meant to be used by anything other than O-Saft itself.

Comment: @melpomene -- You are correct.  I found the problem with the Install.sh --check command kept telling me to try to use cpan to install the missing modules. The modules I wanted to use were in the net subdirectory of the git sources.  The problem with o-saft.pl was the first line of the script -- #!/usr/bin/perl.  I'm using freebsd and the my perl was located within #!/usr/local/bin/perl.  I modified the script and it worked as the instructions stated it would.  Took me about an hour to figure this one out --

Answer (score 1):

Just `use` them in your Perl program. When you run it, it will complain about them not being in `@INC` and tell you what directories are in `@INC`.

Put them in one of those directories or modify your include path.

```
[ ~ ] ➜  perl -MExample -e"echo 1";
Can't locate Example.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Example module) (@INC contains: /Users/quentin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.0-RC1/lib/site_perl/5.26.0/darwin-2level /Users/quentin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.0-RC1/lib/site_perl/5.26.0 /Users/quentin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.0-RC1/lib/5.26.0/darwin-2level /Users/quentin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.0-RC1/lib/5.26.0).
```